# Spin vector representation for 1/2 spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, observables

I know that, for 1/2 spin systems, the projection of the spin vector along one of the base's axis can be represented using Pauli's matrices as $\hat{S}_i = \frac{\hbar}{2}\sigma_i$.

While studying spin-orbit coupling I've seen the actual spin vector being written as $\vec{S}=\frac{\hbar}{2} \vec{\sigma}$.
This expression confuses me since I don't understand what $\vec{\sigma}$ and $\vec{S}$ actually are: vectors with operators as coordinates?

Moreover, the Hamiltonian of the SO interaction is proportional to $\vec{B} \cdot \vec{S}$. Although I understand the physical meaning (potential energy of a magnetic dipole in a magnetic field), I don't know how to evaluate the dot product: if $\vec{S}$ is really a vector of operators, should I multiply each operator for the corresponding component of $\vec{B}$?

And if that is the case, what is the physical meaning of a vector with operators as coordinates?

Comment: $\vec{S}$ is a vector where each component is a matrix.

Comment: It is called the "Pauli vector", checkable in Wikipedia.

Comment: Related: [Rigorous mathematical definition of vector operator?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/327494/)

Answer (score 1):

The spin vector $\vec{S}$ is indeed a vector of operators acting on your spin system, made up of the two $|{\uparrow}\rangle$ and $|{\downarrow}\rangle$ spin states. In other words, each component of the spin vector is a pauli matrix, i.e.,
$$
S_x = \frac{\hbar}{2} \sigma_x
$$
$$
S_y = \frac{\hbar}{2} \sigma_y
$$
$$
S_z = \frac{\hbar}{2} \sigma_z
$$

When evaluating the $\vec{B} \cdot \vec{S}$ product, you can then use the dot product in its regular form, such that
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\vec{B} \cdot \vec{S} &=& B_x S_x + B_y S_y + B_z S_z \\
&=& \frac{\hbar}{2} \left( B_x \sigma_x + B_y \sigma_y + B_z \sigma_z\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
which is a 2 by 2 matrix with the coordinates of $\vec{B}$ inside, depending on the orientation of $\vec{B}$.