# Is there a mathematically rigorous formalization of "operator-valued vectors" from quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, mathematical-physics, vectors

I've seen in various quantum mechanics courses people define various "operator-valued vectors" for the case of three-dimensional systems. For example, people define momentum as $\hat{\vec{p}} = \hat{p}_{x}\vec{e}_{x} + \hat{p}_{y}\vec{e}_{y} + \hat{p}_{z}\vec{e}_{z}$. This is also invoked when we talk about angular momentum.

Shankar does this in his *Principle of Quantum Mechanics* book, for a specific example.

Is these a sense in which this can be mathematically formalized? What is the rigorous way to treat these kinds of objects?

Comment: not sure what you mean by rigorous, but it has always been helpful to me to think of these objects as an ordered collection of operators. In other words, instead of thinking of the angular momentum "operator" as an "operator-valued vector", you can instead think of the object as three (plain-old) operators (with certain transformation properties).

Comment: Indeed, what does "rigorous" mean? You have elements in some space of operator and make (finite!) linear combinations. This is as rigorous as it can get.

Comment: Unless I’m gravely mistaken, such operators always appear in the form of a scalar product with well-defined meaning, *v.g.* $\hat r\cdot \hat p=x p_x+ yp_y+z p_z$ and never as “stand alone” quantities.  The sum of products of operators is well defined.

Comment: You might want to look at this question I have posted some years ago: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327494/rigorous-mathematical-definition-of-vector-operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it is this : consider operators valued in the tensor product of the Hilbert space of states and some vector space, which transform in the right way under rotations (or more generally, under the symmetry transformations of your system). I don't know if this done properly in some textbook.

Let $\mathcal H$ be the Hilbert space of quantum states. We assume that it represents some system of particles in euclidean space $E_3$ (For simplicity, we consider only integer spin particles). For every rotation $R:E_3 \to E_3$, there is a corresponding unitary operator $U(R) : \mathcal H \to \mathcal H$, such that if $R,R'$ are two rotations, then :
$$U(RR') = U(R)U(R')$$

Then, the position operator $\hat{X}$ is a map $\mathcal H\to E_3\otimes \mathcal H$, which we can define by :
$$\forall x \in E_3, \hat X |x\rangle = x\otimes |x\rangle$$

For this collection of operators to truly be a vector, we need it to correctly transform under rotations. For any $x \in E_3$ and a rotation $R$ we have $U(R)|x\rangle=|Rx\rangle $ and therefore :
\begin{align}
\left(\mathbb I_{E_3}\otimes U(R)^\dagger\right)\hat XU(R)|x\rangle &= \left(\mathbb I_{E_3}\otimes U(R)^\dagger\right)\hat X|Rx\rangle \\
 &= \left(\mathbb I_{E_3}\otimes U(R)^\dagger\right)(Rx\otimes |Rx\rangle) \\
&= Rx \otimes |x\rangle \\
&= \left(R\otimes \mathbb I_{\mathcal H}\right)\hat X|x\rangle
\end{align}
and therefore :
$$\left(\mathbb I_{E_3}\otimes U(R)^\dagger\right)\hat X U(R) = \left(R\otimes \mathbb I_{\mathcal H}\right)\hat X$$

In the same way, we define a vector value momentum operator $\hat P : \mathcal H\to E_3 \otimes \mathcal H$. We can then give a basis invariant formulation of :
$$[X^i, P^j] = i\hbar \delta^{ij}$$
Likewise, the angular momentum $\hat L = \frac{1}{m}\hat X\times \hat P$ can be defined in a basis invariant way from $\hat X$ and $\hat P$

**Edit** How to make sense of the fact that $\hat X$ is self adjoint ? Since the components of $\hat X$ in any basis are self-adjoint, we see that for any linear map $\ell :E_3 \to \mathbb R$, the operator $(\ell \otimes \mathbb I_{\mathcal H})\hat X : \mathcal H\to\mathcal H$ is self-adjoint.

Actually, since $E_3$ has a scalar product, we can directly define the adjoint of $\hat X$ as a map $\hat X^\dagger : E_3 \otimes \mathcal H \to \mathcal H$.

Then, if $\ell \in E_3^*$, we have :
\begin{align}
(\ell \otimes \mathbb I_{\mathcal H})\hat X  &= \left((\ell \otimes \mathbb I_{\mathcal H})\hat X \right)^\dagger \\
&= \hat X^\dagger (\ell \otimes \mathbb I_{\mathcal H})^\dagger \\
&= \hat X^\dagger (\ell^\dagger \otimes \mathbb I_{\mathcal H}) \\
\end{align}
where $\ell^\dagger$ is the unique vector in $E_3$ such that :
$$\forall x \in E_3, (\ell^\dagger,x) = \ell(x)$$

Comment: This is not a good way to look at it, you cannot write anything analogous to $\vec{\hat{X}}\vert x\rangle = x\otimes\vert x\rangle$ for the spin-operator $\vec{\hat{S}}$ because no state in the Hilbert space is a simultaneous eigenstate of any two spin operators.

Comment: True, but one can still define a vector-valued spin operator, which transforms correctly under rotations, for example by : $\vec{\hat S}= \vec e_x \otimes  \hat S_x  + \vec e_y \otimes \hat S_y + \vec e_z \otimes \hat S_z $

Comment: Of course! I am not disagreeing with that part. I am disagreeing with the part that is not true of most vector operators but is simply incidental of the vector operators whose components commute.

Comment: It might be a naive question, but since e.g. $X$ must be self-adjoint, shouldn't it be a map from from a vector space to the same vector space?

Answer (score 2):

There's really not much to define - a vector of $n$ operators is the same as a vector of $n$ numbers: just an element of the vector space $O^n$, where $O$ is your vector space of operators (usually some linear operators on a Hilbert space). Then you can say that $\vec p = (p_x,p_y,p_z)\in O^3$.

Answer (score 1):

In quantum field theory, it turns out that the correct formulation is through vector bundles. Their sections are vector fields. To be completely correct we also would have to use the language of distributions. Generally for a vector bundle $E$, we write $\Gamma E$ for its sheaf of sections.

Given a manifold $M$, there is a canonical vector bundle, the tangent bundle $TM$ and its vector fields are tangent fields. This also induces another canonical bundle, the cotangent bundle $T^*M$ and its vector fields are called the cotangent fields.

From this we can construct the exterior cotangent bundle $\wedge T^*M$. It's fields are the exterior cotangent fields - aka differential forms. The sheaf of differential forms is usually written as $\Omega^*(M)$. Thus we have:

> $\Omega^*(M) = \Gamma (\wedge T^*M)$

Now, an $E$-valued differential form over the manifold $M$ is a field of $\wedge TM \otimes E$. We write the sheaf of these as:

> $\Omega^*(M,E) := \Gamma( \wedge T^*M \otimes E)$

And an operator valued differential form is a $End(E)$-valued differential form. That is a section of $\wedge TM \otimes End(E)$. We write the sheaf of these as:

> $\Omega^*(M,EndE) = \Gamma( \wedge T^*M \otimes EndE)$

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? I want to know.

Comment: OP asks about vector-valued *operator* (ie self-adjoint maps on the Hilbert space of states), while this answer deals with vector values *fields* (generalizing maps from space-time to some fixed vector space). (The downvote is not from me though)

Comment: @SolubleFish: A self-adjoint operator is still an operator. I'm not sure what your criticism of a 'field' is supposed to achieve. Have you not heard of a field of operators? This is what I mention in my last paragraph when I define an *operator* valued field.

Comment: OP's question, translated to QFT, would be like : consider $\hat P^\mu = \int \text d^3\vec x \{\text{some expression in terms of local quantum fields}\}$. Then, how to properly formalize the fact that $P^\mu$ is a $4$-vector ? I don't think bundles are relevant here.

Comment: @SolubleFish: No. That's not what he said. He asked for a formal definition of an "operator valued vector".

Comment: The example he gives is specifically $\hat P = \hat p_x \vec e_x + \ldots$

Comment: @SolubleFish: And what do you mean by "vector valued fields"? I described in my last paragraph "operator valued fields". Are you not aware that the space of operators forms a vector space itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133967/discussion-between-solublefish-and-mozibur-ullah).

Comment: @solubleFish: So what? I wasn't attempting to give a concrete description but the abstract picture and that ties in with his request to describe "operator valued vectors".

Comment: @solubleFish: No thanks, on the basis of recent experiece I doubt you want to chat.